# Android 2 columns in table

Tags: android, xml

How you can create a table for android apps with exact 2 columns, so that the 2 columns are filled in the whole width and it is separated in 2 sides proportionally? Normally it looks like this in my case: http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/2798/bingju4q_png.htm. (I am developing a simple BMI Calculator) But I want that both sides are in center.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<TextView android:text="Welcome" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:text="Welcome" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```